# Adding unit tests to visual studio 2017 load test

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, performance-testing, load-testing

I'm spiking on running unit tests as part of load test in visual studio 2017. I created a "Web Performance and Load Test Project" and added a simple unit test in the project.

```
[TestClass]
public class NotificationsTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void AssociateUserToDeviceTest(){
      // Unit Test Code 
    }
}
```

While filling details in 'load test' wizard ('projects' menu > load test), in "test mix" section when I click "add", "There are no tests available to pick" is displayed. From what I understand I should be able to find the unit tests in the project.

[image]

Could anyone please help me with what I'm missing and how can I added unit test load test. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have the tests target the correct framework dll manually.

VS Load Test will not detect unit tests in newer versions.

Reference the following assembly instead of the MSTest.TestFramework nuget.

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework v10.0.0.0
```

It should be found at

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll
```

This also limits the applicable mstest versions. But since this whole feature is being deprecated there's not much else to be said.

Comment: it even works with assemby version 15 in the directory you specified!

Comment: I suspect there are several versions that might work. I could not get it working with the nuget MSTest, but you could probably write an adapter with relative ease.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried compiling the whole solution before adding the load test?

If that doesn't work, you will need to create the unit test in its own Unit Test Project, then you will be able to see it in your load test project.